# No route error for images refereed to by javascript stylesheets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I just migrated my rails 2.3 application to rails 3.2 (a bit late but I did it)

Everything else seem to work fine except I get no route  error for images which are referred to by javascript stylesheets.

The rake assets:precompile task creates all the image names with appended hash also for images which are required by js stylesheets for example jquery dialog etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what path are the images referring to?

Comment: Exactly this was the problem. CSS was referring to images/file.png and the images were in images /custom-theme/images.  Make an answer out of the comment, I will accept it.